# Normal Flip Modifier

Tags: modifiers, objects, normals

I have 8 objects sharing the same mesh (linked duplicates) and I want half of them to have their normals flipped, so I am searching for a modifier that flips all the normals on an object before I set out to write my own.

The mesh is asymmetric, so I can't use a negative scale. The two normal directions need to be separate objects so I can export them to different files for render order reasons. I'd prefer not to have two meshes, as then I'd have to keep them in sync if I edit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Blender 3.0 the [Solidify + Weld Modifier combination](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200726) stopped working - the flipped faces are removed when welding instead of the original ones.

As of Blender 3.1 it is possible to Flip *Faces* with a Geometry Nodes Modifier and a [Mesh > Flip Faces node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/flip_faces.html). This node reverses the order of vertices for each face, which implicitly flips the face normals - it does not flip vertex normals.

While not the Normal Flip Modifier I originally asked for, the Face Flip node is doing what I needed the modifier for.

Answer (score 12):

One solution would be a *Solidify Modifier*.
All credits to @lemon for making it work.

1. Add Solidify Modifier
2. Set *Normals > Flip*, and *Mode > Complex*
3. Add *Weld Modifier*

[image]

Comment: Not so silly (and there is a gif here!)... just set it to "complex" (0 thickness and flip normals) and add a weld modifier.

Comment: Damn it, Lemon! That's the *one* combination of Solidify and Weld I didn't try before! :)

Comment: An advice: for each version of Blender, try every combination of everything... (on my side, still working on 2.59 nowadays...)

Comment: ahah better start working on it quick :D

Comment: Though, weld could merge that is not wanted to be...

Comment: But it works perfectly on Suzanne :). Exactly 500 faces before/after.

Comment: Suzanne is an easter egg, didn't you know? ; )

Comment: + @lemon That's _Evil_.

Comment: Thanks! A little awkward to have to add and configure two modifiers, but it works and is a lot easier than writing my own modifier. It looks like it might destroy custom normals though?

Comment: @Road-hog123 Hi :). Keeps custom normals on my end, but if you've ran into any problems, feel free to post another question.