# How do I flip normals on a shrinkwrap modified shape? (Blender in 2.79.)

Tags: normals

I've created a "Smart Watch" model (with screen) in Blender 2.79. I used the "shrinkwrap" modifier over a square to create a rounded square, then added a flattened cube for the screen.

When I import my model into my game, the outside of the case is transparent to where I see the insides of my watch.

Everything I've [found online](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction) about flipping Normals does not appear to work with a "modified" object. Solutions refer to menu options I simply don't have (or can't find.)

Likewise, applying a "Solidify" modifier (as [another link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200722/normal-flip-modifier) suggests) absorbs my screen and watch stem/button into one big rounded cube (even though the only selected mesh is the case.)

How do I flip the Normals of just my shrinkwrapped cube so the textures on my imported watch face out instead of in? TIA.

[image]

I used the following YT video to create the rounded case:
 [Blender Tutorial: Create A Cube With Round Edges. The Easy Way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aC6M6zYgAg)

Comment: I used the following YT video to create the rounded case. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aC6M6zYgAg

Comment: Ok. If you plan to make no more changes with the results of the modifier, I might just apply it, and work with that. However, it is odd that the normals would be inverted., Will try to review the video, but in the meantime you might do better off just to bevel a cube than use shrink wrap.

Comment: can you explain why you use shrinkwrap to create a rounded square? I agree with Zargul - "normally" you would try bevel or subdivide...but maybe you have a good reason for this...?

Comment: hello, could you please show images in your question? It would really help to understand

Comment: Thx for the replies. I used "shrinkwrap" b/c I'm a novice and that was the solution I found to create a box with rounded corners. Please note there is an image link at the end of my question showing the result. TIA

Comment: Your image was shown as a link but not as an embedded image because the markup was slightly messed up (missing '!'). It's nows fixed.

Comment: No one was able to provide a solution to flipping the Normals of a shrinkwrapped box, so I resorted to using the suggested "subdivide" method: Using the "Subdivision Surface" modifier and "Loop Cut and Slide". This produces the same basic shape where the object itself is deformed instead of a wrapped "cover", so the Normals are never changed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBmxfNysftA